# How formulate a SQL query that needs to mention four different tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I want to get the Company name and all the products they purchased in a single SQL query.

The database used is the Northwind sample database.
The relations between these columns and dbs' tables look like this:

```
ProductName <- [T]Products     -> [K]ProductID
                                       /\
                                       ||
                                       \/
               [T]OrderDetails -> [K]ProductID
                               .. [K]OrderID
                                       /\
                                       ||
                                       \/
               [T]Orders       -> [K]OrderID
                               .. [K]CustomerID
                                       /\
                                       ||
                                       \/
CompanyName <- [T]Customers    -> [K]CustomerID
```

Where [T] is a table and [K] are the table's keys.

I tried to get at least the corresponding Product name, but SQL Server says that such inclusion is invalid.

```sql
SELECT ProductName
  FROM Products
 WHERE ProductID IN (SELECT ProductID
                       FROM [Order Details]
                      WHERE OrderID IN (SELECT OrderID, CustomerID
                                          FROM Orders));
```

How do I mention four different tables in one query?

Comment: You should use [joins](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question should be answered by consulting product documentation or an available online tutorial. Stack Overflow is not the appropriate forum for the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be looking for joins:

```
select distinct c.companyName, p.productName
from customers c
inner join orders o on o.customerID = c.customerID
inner join orderdetails od on od.orderID = o.orderID
inner join products p on p.productID = od.productID
```

This gives, for each company, the list of all (distinct) products that were purchased by its customers.